# C++ STL Next Permutation with Combination

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, combinations, permutation

I know that I can use `std::next_permutation` on some container containing the elements `[1, 2, 3]` which would generate 6 permutations of this sequence. What I would like to do is given some set `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` generate all possible permutations of size 3. So for this example, `[4, 3, 2]` would be one of the permutations resulting from this criteria. I'm looking for an STL way of doing this (if possible) rather than writing my own combinations function. Any particular STL implementation I should be reading about ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430568/generating-combinations-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991758/creating-all-possible-k-combinations-of-n-items-in-c

Comment: @AlanStokes: all those questions concern combinations; this question is about permutations.

Comment: It's about permuting combinations. And the OP knows how to permute, which just leaves finding the combinations. Hence "I'm looking for an STL way of doing this [...] rather than writing my own combinations function".

Answer (score 3):

There is currently (as of 2016) no single STD function to do that. The closest you have is the proposal from http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2639.pdf

The function you want is called `next_partial_permutation` and looks like (from N2639):

```
template  <class  BidirectionalIterator >
bool next_partial_permutation(
  BidirectionalIterator  first ,
  BidirectionalIterator  middle ,
  BidirectionalIterator  last)
{
  std::reverse(middle , last);
  return std::next_permutation(first , last);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not the most efficient possible algorithm but it's easy. You must start with the elements sorted. To get the next k-permutation, reverse the last n-k elements and then try to get the next permutation. The first k elements are the next k-permutation.

Comment: Seems obvious now that you say it, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm written in Smalltalk.

The idea of the algorithm is to consider the lexicographic order of arrays of length `m` with elements between `1` and `n`. Given any such `array`, the method `next` replaces `array` with its next partial permutation in said order.

I've created a class with three instance variables

```
array       the current permutation of length m
m           the size of array
complement  the SortedCollection of integers not in array
```

The instance creation method `m:n:` works as follows

```
m: length n: limit
  m := length.
  array := (1 to: m) asArray.
  complement := (m + 1 to: limit) asSortedCollection
```

In this class the method `next` modifies the `array` so that it will now hold the next permutation.

It might be worth mentioning that the algorithm is not recursive.

The method `next` answers with `nil` iff `array` contains the last permutation in the order (i.e., `array = (n, n-1, ...., n-m+1)`.

To compute all permutations start with `array = (1 ... m)` and send `next` until the answer is `nil`.

```
next
  | index max h a c |
  index := self lastDecreasingIndex.
  max := complement max.
  h := (index to: m) findLast: [:i | (array at: i) < max] ifAbsent: nil.
  h isNil
    ifTrue: [
      index = 1 ifTrue: [^nil].
      a := array at: index - 1.
      index to: m do: [:i | complement add: (array at: i)].
      c := complement detect: [:cj | a < cj].
      array at: index - 1 put: c.
      complement remove: c; add: a.
      index to: m do: [:i | array at: i put: complement removeFirst]]
    ifFalse: [
      h := h + index - 1.
      a := array at: h.
      c := complement detect: [:ci | a < ci].
      array at: h put: c.
      complement remove: c; add: a.
      h + 1 to: m do: [:i | complement add: (array at: i)].
      h + 1 to: m do: [:i | array at: i put: complement removeFirst]]
```

Where

```
lastDecreasingIndex
  | index |
  index := m.
  [(array at: index - 1) > (array at: index)] whileTrue: [
    index := index - 1.
    index = 1 ifTrue: [^1]].
  ^index
```